# ContentResolver.openOutputStream() throws strage FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, file-descriptor, storage-access-framework

My purpose is to be able to edit files on removable external storage on Android 21+. To do so, it must be used the Storage Access Framework.

First I granted the read and write permissions to the folder I'm interested in with:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 123);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent resultData) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;
    Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();

    PreferenceUtils.setPersistedUri(this, treeUri);

    grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

I'm sure this is done correctly because I double check it:

```
for(UriPermission uri : getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions())
            if(uri.isReadPermission() && uri.isWritePermission())
                // This prints the correct folder
```

If relevant, I also declared in manifest and requested runtime permissions for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

```
DocumentFile parentDocumentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getActivity(), PreferenceUtils.getPersistedUri());
if(parentDocumentFile == null) return;
for(DocumentFile file : parentDocumentFile.listFiles()) {
    if(file.canRead() && file.canWrite() && file.exists()) {
        try 
        {
             OutputStream outStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(file.getUri());

             // I/O operations
        } (catch FileNotFoundException e) {}
    }        
}
```

Later in the code, I get a reference to the file I'm interested in with a content URI wrapped by `DocumentFile`. I want to underline that `DocumentFile.exists()`, `DocumentFile.canRead()`, `DocumentFile.canWrite()` return positive result, also a check with system `File.exists()` has been done. For instance, the URI I get with `DocumentFile.getUri()` looks like:

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/486E-2542%3A/document/486E-2542%3ADownload%2FFildoDownloads%2FLed%20Zeppelin%2FLed%20Zeppelin%20-%20Kashmir.mp3

Alright here. But if I wanted to open it for writing, I can't and this is the only available method to write a file which permissions are granted through the Storage Access Framework:

```
OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(DocumentFile.getUri());
```

Some devices (and I cannot reproduce) throw a `FileNotFoundExcpetion` with the following stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Failed opening content provider: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/486E-2542%3A/document/486E-2542%3ADownload%2FFildoDownloads%2FLed%20Zeppelin%2FLed%20Zeppelin%20-%20Kashmir.mp3
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1032)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:718)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:694)
    at helpers.c.b(SourceFile:405)
```

Some other with this one:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Failed to open for writing: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Read-only file system
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:621)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1011)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:753)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:729)
    at helpers.c.b(SourceFile:405)
```

This doesn't happen *very often*, let's say about 1 device out 200, but it still a relevant problem since breaks the main purpose of the app so the user can just uninstall it.

All past questions on StackOverflow looks similar to this but the solution there was not to write in the root of the storage, which is obviously not the problem here.
I really have no clue with these exceptions in this particular scenario, so I might ask if anyone is aware of possible situations that make impossible to obtain a file descriptor with write access to a file.

Comment: Please show complete code. Just put all relevant code in onActivityResult().

Comment: `Led%20Zeppelin%2FLed%20Zeppelin` translates to `Led/Zeppelin/Led/Zeppelin` You really have two Led and two Zeppelin directories?

Comment: `grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);`. You better remove that line. You cannot grant yourself permissions. You can only take them here as you do in the next statement.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for the suggestion, updated code. That user probably has two folders. No this translates to: `/486E-2542/Download/FildoDownloads/Led Zeppelin/Led Zeppelin - Kashmir.mp3`

Comment: `If relevant, I also declared in manifest and requested runtime permissions for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGEand WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.`. Nit needed.

Comment: You choose a folder. Please also give full content scheme of folder. Then you somewhere construct an uri for a file in it. But how deep that file is is unclear. And how you construct the uri too. So show complete code.

Comment: @greenapps I'm not constructing anything. I ask the user to choose the folder in which the target files are contained, then I cycle & edit all the files contained in that directory As far as I know, this is the most straight forward method.

Comment: You are not doing that loop without an `outStream.close();` are you?

Comment: @greenapps of course I close everything up, but that can't be the problem since users reported the error pops up without not even the first file was edited so the exception is thrown on the first cycle

Comment: So you are going to delete all files in that directory? As that is what openOutputStream() does. Why all delete?

Comment: You are checking if the file is writable. You could also check before if the directory is writable.

Comment: Taking the persisted uri permissiins there is a flag indicating if the directory is writable. Did you use it?

Comment: To refresh your memory about `openOutputStream`: developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openOutputStream(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String). There is clearly a piece of code where I double check read and write permissions for the directory.

Comment: IMO, the exception message is interesting. "Read-only file system" — means, that either of these things happened: 1. SD-card (since SAF volumes are usually backed by  SD cards) has been mounted read-only 2. There is a bug in kernel/storaged/ContentProvider. There are several reasons, why SD card might be mounted read only, for example severe filesystem corruption. Either way, the problem might just be fixed after user takes out and re-inserts SD card. You may obtain additional information by trying to open a file read-only. Also consider sending content of /proc/self/mountinfo to Crashlytics

Comment: @user1643723 this is interesting, I will try to contact again that user

Comment: `To refresh your memory about openOutputStream: `. It is unclear what you wanna tell. Now did you look at the write flags? And did you check writability of obtained tree before those write operations?

Comment: @fillobotto looking at contents of `/proc/self/mountinfo` is especially useful, because that will immediately show, whether filesystem is mounted read-only or not. If it is actually not read-only and/or retrying the call another time or from different application produces different results, this may be a system bug. Just in case, — certain manufacturers (e.g. Samsung) have their own buggy filesystem solutions, so knowing a device model can be valuable in debugging this.

Comment: `and this is the only available method to write a file which permissions are granted through the Storage Access Framework:`. Which luckily is not true.

Comment: @greenapps "did you look at the write flags? And did you check writability of obtained tree before those write operations?" — I don't think there is a **good** way to check for real writability of DocumentFile. As can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentsContractApi19.java#DocumentsContractApi19.canWrite%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.net.Uri%29), calling `canWrite` on DocumentFile only checks it's flags. I doubt, that SAF DocumentProvider actually checks if partition is writable

Comment: @user##.. Interesting. Thanks. Then indeed try to write to a file and you know. Old story. On some Android 5 devices File.canWrite/) would return true where you could not. So had to try first.

Comment: Let those users test on primary: partition instead of sd card.

Comment: @user1643723 the user reinserted the SD card and now everything works perfectly. I knew it could not be a code-side problem... If you elaborate a short answer, I'll mark it as accepted even though it's not strictly programming-related

Comment: @fillobotto "it's not strictly programming-related", — I disagree. Very often a complex problem can be solved by re-plugging a cable. But if software offers a way to check whether cable is properly plugged, It is still programming-related.

Comment: @fillobotto About another error you got — "Failed opening content provider". This is also very suspicious (and the biggest reason, why I suspected filesystem corruption). That message basically means, that SD card DocumentProvider just crashed. In that case your best bet is to let user retry the operation (in hopes, that Android will be able to restart ContentProvider by that time). I doubt, that other apps can handle that better :) Alternatively, that may means, that your app is so buggy and full of leaks, that it can't even interact with system anymore (that's unlikely to be unnoticed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message in your exception says "Read-only file system". That message is typically associated with native errno ["EROFS"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), which happens when a Linux process tries to open a file on read-only storage for writing.

There are multiple reasons, why a storage can be mounted read-only. For example, most file systems are automatically re-mounted read-only by kernel in case of severe data corruption (Android system might not even realize, that device SD card has switched to read-only mode).

It also might happen because of bugs in Android system code. In that case, knowing device vendor and model might be useful for debugging.

The simplest solution: try to open the file in read-only mode if opening for writing fails. If read-only open succeeds, the problem can probably be solved by ejecting and re-inserting SD card (that should cause Android to automatically run fsck on it).

```
Uri uri = file.getUri();

try (OutputStream o = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri))
{
  // I/O operations
} (catch FileNotFoundException e) {
    try (OutputStream s = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) {
         // the file can be opened for reading, but not for writing
         // ask user to reinsert SD card and/or disable
         // write protection toggle on it
         Toast.makeText(context, "Please reinsert SD card", LENGTH_SHORT);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
         // This is hopeless, just report error to user
         Toast.makeText(context, err.toString(), LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

If you want to determine, whether a filesystem is actually mounted read-only or not, consider reading from special file `/proc/self/mountinfo`. You can send it's contents to Crashlytics for debugging or even [parse them in your code](https://github.com/chdir/fdutil/blob/aae5319/fdlib/src/main/java/net/sf/xfd/MountInfo.java#L214). You can learn more about per-process `mountinfo` file from [Linux kernel documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Comment: @fillobotto While we are at it, — you should be careful about using `getActivity()` when operating on `Uri`s. Android Storage Access Framework is usually associated with SD cards, but different DocumentProvider implementations (for example Google Drive document provider) may perform network calls and even download entire files from internet when you call `openOutputStream` and other ContentResolver methods. You should call those methods from background thread. You should not assume, that Activity still exists by the time your AsyncTask reaches that code.

Comment: Of course, the snippet I posted was just a MCVE. The actual code was far more complex than this, but again, it was not the problem because it's working fine on 99% of devices. Thank you for all the precious information.

Answer (score -2):

Your code looks fine to me but try this if you want:

```
                ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();


                String myString= "This is what we will write"  ;


                OutputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    stream = cr.openOutputStream(///YourFile///.getUri());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    stream.write(myString.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: That will result in a `NullPointerException` because when `openOutputStream` throws exception then `stream` will be null.

Comment: What do you expect him to accomplish by writing to `null` stream?